# Insert custom field to custom post type

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a component made by a plugin which displays a list of articles from a custom post type. Each article has the class post-id associated with. I can't override plugin's files in child theme to loop inside the template that generates the list so I need to create a function in functions.php. What I need is to replace a div inside the article with a new div styled with a custom field ( color picker ) made with advanced custom field plugin, that is associated to each article dynamically.

```css
    loop {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
    article {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: red;
      margin:20px;
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }
    .overlay {
      width:150px;
      height:150px;
    }
```

```html
    <article class="portfolio-item post-53">
      <div class="overlay" style="background-color:#000"></div>
    </article>
    <article class="portfolio-item post-65">
      <div class="overlay" style="background-color:#000"></div>
    </article>
    <article class="portfolio-item post-70">
      <div class="overlay" style="background-color:#000"></div>
    </article>

   

function insert_custom_div() {

 $args = array(
     'meta_key'    => 'new_color',
     'post_type'   => 'portfolio-item'
   );

$posts = get_posts($args);

   foreach ($posts as $post):
      $color_picker_custom_field = get_field('new_color', $post->ID);

      if ($color_picker_custom_field) {
      ?>
       <script>
           jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
              jQuery('article').append('<div class="overlay post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" style="background-color:<?php echo $color_picker_custom_field; ?>"></div>');

       });
       </script>
     <?php
   }
   endforeach;
}

add_action('wp_head','insert_custom_div');
```

Comment: PErhaps you need to declare `$new_div` as array and populate it within loop of $posts

Answer (score 0):

You can get new color from each post to array and then pass the array to javascript with `json_encode()`

Here is modified fragment of your code, I'm not sure it will work since html injections to functions.php is bad practice, it's better to do it in template. Well it's just direction for thoughts:

```
<?php
$new_div = array();
foreach ($posts as $post):
    $color_picker_custom_field = get_field('new_color', $post->ID);
    $new_div[] = '<div class="overlay" style="background-color:<?php echo $color_picker_custom_field; ?>"></div>';
   endforeach;

?>
<script>
      jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
        var new_divs = <?php echo json_encode($new_div); ?>;
        jQuery( '.overlay' ).each( function(ind, el) {
           jQuery(this).replaceWith(new_divs[ind]');
        });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, unfortunately with your solution the $color_picker_custom_field it is not displayed, but I edited my code with another solution and its working. The only need to do is to add a class to child element of article with the same post-id. So if  I have article.post-id = .overlay.post-id add a class so I can hide the other divs that I don't need